# Sending automatic email on background

Tags: android

I am trying to send an automatic email "in the background" as a notification to the user..
I used this code from the following link, 
[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Although this code seems find, but it didn't work with me. I didn't receive any email. I also used the permission,

here's my code,

EmailSender.java

```
package zaid.project.EmailSender;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

 public class EmailSenderActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



        try {   
            GmailSender sender = new GmailSender(senderEmail@gmail.com", "password");
            sender.sendMail("Griffin Seal test",   
                    "Hellow Guys, this is zaid, sending an automatic email from our application, \n is this a new line ? good luck!",   
                    "senderEmail@gmail.com",   
                    "receiverEmail@hotmail.com");   


   } catch (Exception e) {   
                Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
            } 



     }
   }
```

GmailSender.java

```
  package zaid.project.EmailSender;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties;   

public class GmailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static {   
        Security.addProvider(new JSSEProvider());   
    }  



    public GmailSender(String user2, String password2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);  
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message);   
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}
```

JSSEProvider.java

```
package zaid.project.EmailSender;

/*
 *  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 *  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 *  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 *  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 *  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 *  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */

/**
 * @author Alexander Y. Kleymenov
 * @version $Revision$
 */


import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Anyone can help? Thank you.

my log cat,

```
05-02 16:20:07.636: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(652): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
05-02 16:20:07.636: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(652): CheckJNI is ON
05-02 16:20:09.476: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(652): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
05-02 16:20:09.826: DEBUG/dalvikvm(228): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2K, 54% free 2545K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 194ms
05-02 16:20:09.866: WARN/ActivityManager(68): No content provider found for: 
05-02 16:20:09.986: WARN/ActivityManager(68): No content provider found for: 
05-02 16:20:10.026: DEBUG/PackageParser(68): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl1881124255.tmp
05-02 16:20:10.686: INFO/PackageManager(68): Removing non-system package:zaid.project.EmailSender
05-02 16:20:10.686: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Force stopping package zaid.project.EmailSender uid=10040
05-02 16:20:10.786: INFO/Process(68): Sending signal. PID: 601 SIG: 9
05-02 16:20:10.856: ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): channel '406ccb98 zaid.project.EmailSender/zaid.project.EmailSender.EmailSenderActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
05-02 16:20:10.856: ERROR/InputDispatcher(68): channel '406ccb98 zaid.project.EmailSender/zaid.project.EmailSender.EmailSenderActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
05-02 16:20:10.916: INFO/WindowManager(68): WIN DEATH: Window{406ccb98 zaid.project.EmailSender/zaid.project.EmailSender.EmailSenderActivity paused=false}
05-02 16:20:11.108: WARN/InputManagerService(68): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 601 uid 10040
05-02 16:20:12.036: DEBUG/PackageManager(68): Scanning package zaid.project.EmailSender
05-02 16:20:12.036: INFO/PackageManager(68): Package zaid.project.EmailSender codePath changed from /data/app/zaid.project.EmailSender-1.apk to /data/app/zaid.project.EmailSender-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
05-02 16:20:12.046: INFO/PackageManager(68): Unpacking native libraries for /data/app/zaid.project.EmailSender-2.apk
05-02 16:20:12.120: DEBUG/installd(34): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/zaid.project.EmailSender-2.apk' ---
05-02 16:20:16.995: DEBUG/dalvikvm(661): DexOpt: load 459ms, verify+opt 3535ms
05-02 16:20:17.125: DEBUG/installd(34): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/zaid.project.EmailSender-2.apk' (success) ---
05-02 16:20:17.135: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Force stopping package zaid.project.EmailSender uid=10040
05-02 16:20:17.145: WARN/PackageManager(68): Code path for pkg : zaid.project.EmailSender changing from /data/app/zaid.project.EmailSender-1.apk to /data/app/zaid.project.EmailSender-2.apk
05-02 16:20:17.145: WARN/PackageManager(68): Resource path for pkg : zaid.project.EmailSender changing from /data/app/zaid.project.EmailSender-1.apk to /data/app/zaid.project.EmailSender-2.apk
05-02 16:20:17.159: DEBUG/PackageManager(68):   Activities: zaid.project.EmailSender.EmailSenderActivity
05-02 16:20:17.275: DEBUG/dalvikvm(228): GC_EXPLICIT freed 7K, 54% free 2543K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 739ms
05-02 16:20:17.776: INFO/installd(34): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@zaid.project.EmailSender-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@zaid.project.EmailSender-2.apk@classes.dex
05-02 16:20:17.785: DEBUG/PackageManager(68): New package installed in /data/app/zaid.project.EmailSender-2.apk
05-02 16:20:18.197: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Force stopping package zaid.project.EmailSender uid=10040
05-02 16:20:18.535: DEBUG/dalvikvm(136): GC_EXPLICIT freed 47K, 53% free 2846K/5959K, external 4796K/5329K, paused 327ms
05-02 16:20:18.645: DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_EXPLICIT freed 838K, 49% free 4349K/8455K, external 3125K/3903K, paused 370ms
05-02 16:20:19.195: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(68): no available voice recognition services found
05-02 16:20:20.295: DEBUG/dalvikvm(68): GC_EXPLICIT freed 232K, 50% free 4287K/8455K, external 3125K/3903K, paused 326ms
05-02 16:20:20.295: DEBUG/dalvikvm(187): GC_EXPLICIT freed 109K, 52% free 2764K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 1506ms
05-02 16:20:20.435: INFO/installd(34): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@zaid.project.EmailSender-1.apk@classes.dex
05-02 16:20:20.469: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(652): Shutting down VM
05-02 16:20:20.515: INFO/AndroidRuntime(652): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
05-02 16:20:20.535: DEBUG/dalvikvm(652): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 72% free 295K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 6ms+2ms
05-02 16:20:20.575: DEBUG/dalvikvm(652): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
05-02 16:20:22.055: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(666): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
05-02 16:20:22.055: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(666): CheckJNI is ON
05-02 16:20:24.115: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(666): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
05-02 16:20:24.215: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=zaid.project.EmailSender/.EmailSenderActivity } from pid 666
05-02 16:20:24.335: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(666): Shutting down VM
05-02 16:20:24.415: INFO/AndroidRuntime(666): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
05-02 16:20:24.435: DEBUG/dalvikvm(666): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 69% free 318K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 7ms+3ms
05-02 16:20:24.435: DEBUG/jdwp(666): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
05-02 16:20:24.435: DEBUG/dalvikvm(666): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
05-02 16:20:24.575: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Start proc zaid.project.EmailSender for activity zaid.project.EmailSender/.EmailSenderActivity: pid=676 uid=10040 gids={3003}
05-02 16:20:28.045: INFO/ActivityManager(68): Displayed zaid.project.EmailSender/.EmailSenderActivity: +3s730ms
05-02 16:20:33.266: DEBUG/dalvikvm(324): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2K, 54% free 2539K/5511K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 132ms
05-02 16:20:34.175: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
05-02 16:20:38.365: DEBUG/dalvikvm(136): GC_EXPLICIT freed 88K, 52% free 2907K/5959K, external 4845K/5329K, paused 202ms
05-02 16:20:43.427: DEBUG/dalvikvm(282): GC_EXPLICIT freed 8K, 55% free 2597K/5767K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 209ms
```

Comment: logCat is updated in the post.

Comment: I am also getting this one,

05-02 16:50:34.376: DEBUG/SntpClient(68): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol

Comment: Did you add jar files? Did you add your username and password in EmailSender.java?